# How do I cast a pointer to a Qt4 form

Tags: casting, qt4, qt-designer

I have Qt4 from(WorkersList) required by other forms to pass back some values, those forms will call WorkersList, and then WorkersList will pass back values depend on the form that make the call. In order to pass back values from WorkersList to the caller, I have to implement a method for each of those forms like this:

*pseudo code:*

```
class WorkersList : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit WorkersList(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void getWorkersList();
    void setWorkerForm(Ui::WorkerMod *workerMod); // The method to pass back to the caller 1
    void setWorkerForm2(Ui::WorkerDel *workerDel); // The method to pass back to the caller 2
    void setSuspendForm(Ui::WorkerSuspend *worker); // The method to pass back to the caller 3
    void setResumeForm(Ui::WorkerResume *worker); // The method to pass back to the caller 4
    ~WorkersList();

private:
    Ui::WorkersList *ui;
    Ui::WorkerMod *workerForm;
    Ui::WorkerDel *workerForm2;
    Ui::WorkerSuspend *workerSuspendForm;
    Ui::WorkerResume *workerResumeForm;
    QStringList infoWorker;
};
```

Is there a way that make I have only to implement one method, pass the caller as an argument, and from the method I made the cast to the caller like this:

```
class WorkersList : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit WorkersList(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void getWorkersList();
    void setForm(void *from, int caller); 
    ~WorkersList();

private:
    Ui::WorkersList *ui;
    Ui::WorkerMod *workerForm;
    Ui::WorkerDel *workerForm2;
    Ui::WorkerSuspend *workerSuspendForm;
    Ui::WorkerResume *workerResumeForm;
    QStringList infoWorker;
};

...

void WorkersList::setForm(void *form, int caller)
{
    if(caller == 0)
        workerForm = (Ui::WorkerMod *)form;
    else if(caller == 1)
        workerForm2 = (Ui::WorkerDel *)form;
    else if(caller == 2)
        workerSuspendForm = (Ui::WorkerSuspend *)form;
    else if(caller == 3)
        workerResumeForm = (Ui::WorkerResume *)form;

}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried this:

```
void WorkersList::setForm(QObject *obj, int form)
{
    if(form == 0)
    {
        this->workerAbsenceForm = qobject_cast<Ui::AbsenceAdd *>(obj);
    }
    if(form == 1)
    {
        this->workerAbsenceForm3 = qobject_cast<Ui::AbsenceMod >(obj);
    }
}
```

The Compiler produces this errors:

```
/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore/qobject.h: In function 'T qobject_cast(QObject*) [with T = Ui::AbsenceAdd*]':
workerslist.cpp:259:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore/qobject.h:378: error: 'class Ui::AbsenceAdd' has no member named 'qt_check_for_QOBJECT_macro'
/usr/local/include/qt4/QtCore/qobject.h:380: error: 'class Ui::AbsenceAdd' has no member named 'staticMetaObject'
```

And the other hint I tried:

```
void WorkersList::setForm(void *obj, int form)
{
    if(form == 0)
    {
        this->workerAbsenceForm = (Ui::AbsenceAdd *)obj;
    }
    if(form == 1)
    {
        this->workerAbsenceForm3 = (Ui::AbsenceMod *)obj;
    }
}
```

It does compile, but the GUI never showed up.

Answer (score 1):

If all these forms inherit QWidget you can use meta-object information of the argument passed to the setForm() method.

```
void WorkerList::setForm(QWidget* form)
{
  if (!form)
    return;

  const QString name = form->metaObject()->className();

  if (QString::fromUtf8("WorkerMod") == name)
    workerForm = qobject_cast<WorkerMod*>(form);   

  ...
}
```